# Scanner class (system.in) does not work in android studio and with changes in build.gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have problem with Scanner Class in the android studio. I create the New Module in android studio for coding pure java in this. After that I want use the Scanner Class for inputting some element from user but the program generate the following Error.

```java
package org.meicode.lib;
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner In= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Your Name Plz: ");
        String Name= In.next();
    }
}
```

[The Main Class which I used the Scanner and System.in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvCAl.png)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at org.meicode.lib.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:7)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

[The Error After I run the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBxPD.png)

I search in stackoverflow and I see some solution for this problem like adding the

```java
run { standardInput = System.in }
```

but it does not work too, however the build.gradle run with "Task execution finished". you can see my build.gradle before and after the changes. The Lib and the MyClass is the name of my module and the class respectively.

```java
apply plugin: 'java-library'
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

[Build.gradle before changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVPv8.png)

```java
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin:'application'
mainClassName = 'MyClass'

run { standardInput = System.in }
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

[Build.gradle after changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4mGu.png)

I really hope you help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Instead post the code or errors as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with system.in not working. Restarting IDE worked for me.